# MYSQL - Left Join on multiple conditions - Medias & Tags & Tag Links

Tags: mysql, join, count, left-join

I couldn't find anything that matches my issues.

I'm trying to improve my files search query to be able to fetch images by multiple tags (AND and OR).

Fetching images that have one or the other tag is rather easy:

```
SELECT M.*, MTL.tag_id 
FROM medias M 
LEFT JOIN medias_taglinks MTL ON MTL.media_id=M.id 
WHERE ( MTL.tag_id = '1' || MTL.tag_id = '2') 
GROUP BY M.id
```

But if I want to fetch a image that has both of those tags, I get no results and I'm failing to understand why.

```
SELECT M.*, MTL.tag_id 
FROM medias M 
LEFT JOIN medias_taglinks MTL ON MTL.media_id=M.id 
WHERE ( MTL.tag_id = '1' && MTL.tag_id = '2') 
GROUP BY M.id
```

I'm guessing I need to add my condition to the join but I haven't succeeded yet.

SQL FIDDLE HERE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e5d6/4

Comment: An underrated debugging technique with SQL is proper formatting.

Comment: Agreed, some request truly get complicated. :)

Comment: Explain what you expect to get & why. Otherwise what can an answer but yet another presentation of SQL semantics not addressing your misconceptions? Moreover that clarification leads to effective search phrases. Yes this is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Put everything needed in your post.

Comment: What is your question? "Can any of you guys help?" is not a valid question. Your overall goal is a faq. Your 2nd code problem is also a faq. When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it. (Debugging fundamental.) Ask about that.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @philipxy. I'll try to take these points in consideration next time.

Comment: "See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts." "What is your question?" (Etc.) But even if you make this question clear & specific with a [mre] in it (re your overall goal, per the accepted answer) it's still a faq so "shows no reseach" & if you edit it now to say that you found out it's a faq it can still be considered by some as "not useful" because it is a faq. See [help]. If you research, don't just say you did, report what you tried & what you learned. This shouldn't have been answered but some hi-rep users keep answering duplicates instead of closing as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for an image to have two different tags requires comparing values across rows, which, in turns, suggest aggregation:

```
select m.id, m.name
from medias m
inner join medias_taglinks t on t.media_id = m.id
where t.tag_id in (1, 2)
group by m.id, m.name
having min(t.tag_id) <> max(t.tag_id)
```

The query filters on the two searched tags, aggregates by media, and ensures that both tags are present.

In your db fiddle, this produces:

```
id | name
-- | ----
1  | Media 1
```

If you want to handle more than two tags, here is a more generic approach:

```
select m.id, m.name
from medias m
inner join medias_taglinks t on t.media_id = m.id
where t.tag_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
group by m.id, m.name
having count(*) = 4
```

This assumes no duplicate `(media_id, tag_id)` in the tag table; otherwise, you need `having count(distinct t.tag_id) = 4`.

Side note: the `left join` seems unnecessary; if you want to search medias for tags, you need to bring the tab table anyway.

Comment: That's great, that's the result I want. Thanks. However, I don't understand the purpose of the "having line"? Could you explain?

Comment: @oriongu: it filters the groups to ensure that they have all the required tags.

Comment: Ok thanks for explaining @GMB :) Truly appreciated.